# Azure Cloud service get certificate from cloud service

Tags: c#, azure, certificate

I was looking for a way to get all the certificates from a cloud service. Currently I am going through all the azure management api trying to find a way to get to the certificate stored in the cloud service but am having no luck. Is there a way to get to the certificates?

I was looking at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460788.aspx but I am not sure what the dns name is and it doesn't seem to return the expiration date of the cert.

Comment: `what the dns name is` - This is the name of your cloud service. Not sure what you mean by `it doesn't seem to return the expiration date of the cert.`